# URL with large query-string in AFNetworking

Tags: query-string, afnetworking, request.querystring

I'm using AFNetworking in my iPhone application for building an http get request. In general I append all the parameters in the query string. The problem is that one of this parameters is a list of IDs which can become really big (till 4.000 id). How can I manage such a big parameter?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A URL can only be about 2000 characters, so something like what you're describing may not work. Instead, either send as an HTTP body in a POST request, or just divide things up into a few smaller requests.